# Trying to make Host sFlow for XenServer 7.0

Tags: linux, networking, makefile, centos, xen

I spent all day trying to make Host sFlow 2.0.6-1 from sources (https://github.com/sflow/host-sflow/releases) for XenServer 7.0 using the XenServer DDK from this site: http://xenserver.org/overview-xenserver-open-source-virtualization/download.html

First I had to make 2 changes to the file hsflowd-xen.spec:
Changed line 3 to: "Version: 2.0.6" (it was still 2.0.1)
Changed line 20 to: "%setup -n hsflowd-2.0.6-1" (added the name because the default one was wrong).

Now my problem is that I dont have the xenstore.h file. After long searches I found that it's in the package libxen-dev (or libxen-devel) but I couldn't find it with its dependecies anywhere.

The four most probable solutions I think are :
1. (The lazy one) Get the iso file for Host sFlow already built for XenServer 7.0 (the official site stopped building at 6.5)

2. Set up a proper yum repository that will contain libxen-dev and its dependencies. I can't even connect to the official CentOS repositories because the files in /etc/yum.repos.d/ have a bad URL.
   This is the content of /etc/centos-release: "XenServer DDK release 7.0.0-125770c (xenenterprise)"
3. Somehow manage to use 'xenstore.a' instead of 'xenstore.h'. I changed the code in src/Linux/mod_xen.c to include 'xenstore.a' instead of 'xenstore.h' but when I build it, it creates a new file with the old code and ignores my changes. I probably changed the wrong files because there are different copies of the whole code. I'm not even sure it would work though even if I did manage to include 'xenstore.a'.
4. Make xenstore from sources. I didn't try it because I only found old sources and I figured I'd miss the dependencies too.

PS: I'm n00b at CentOS and Makefiles in general so the solution might be obvious and I just don't know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With gratitude to lagange, I updated the host-sflow project with a XenServer 7 build.  I also added a Docker recipe so you can replace all these steps with just "./docker_build_on xenserver".  Please raise issues on https://github.com/sflow/host-sflow.

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeeded in building it. That's what I had to do step by step:

1. Import the XenServer DDK 7.0.0 into XenCenter.
2. Extend xvda1 following these steps: https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX125405
3. Make these changes to hsflowd-xen.spec:

   3rd line: Version: 2.0.6

   20th line: %setup -n hsflowd-2.0.6-1

   Add these two lines before %description:

   %define debug_package %{nil}

   %define _unpackaged_files_terminate_build 0
4. Change file /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base

   Change all occurrences of "$releasever" to "7".

   Change all occurrences of "$basearch" to "x86_64".

   Change "enabled=0" to "enabled=1" for each repository.

   Uncomment baseurl lines for each repository.
5. Mount the Development packages (binpkg.iso available on the xenserver.org download page) and add a file for it in /etc/yum.repos.d/

   Mine looks like it:

   [binpkg]

   name=CitrixXenServer7

   enabled=1

   baseurl=file:///mnt/binpkg/

   gpgcheck=0
6. Install the two following packages with Yum (dependencies should install correctly now):

   xen-libs-devel.x86_64

   xen-dom0-libs-devel.x86_64
7. Make the file and install it using this tutorial: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sflow/host-sflow/v2.0.4/INSTALL.XenServer